# merge/join two data frames using more than one "by"?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have two data frames like the following:

```
df1 = data.frame(ssuid=c(916860000285, 916860000285, 916925451999, 404454000285, 404454000285),
                 epppnum=c(101,102,101,101,102),
                 esex=c("M","F","M","M","F"))

df2 = data.frame(ssuid=c(916860000285, 916860000285, 916925451999, 404454000285, 404454000285),
                 epppnum=c(101,102,101,101,102),
                 erace=c(1,1,2,1,1))
```

I want to merge them, but an unique ID is the combination of ssuid and epppnum. My solution right now is to create a new variable and then use that to merge.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 = df1 %>% mutate(uniqueID=paste(ssuid,epppnum,sep="/")) %>%
  select(uniqueID, esex)
df2 = df2 %>% mutate(uniqueID=paste(ssuid,epppnum,sep="/"))%>%
  select(uniqueID, erace)

df = left_join(df1,df2,by="uniqueID")
```

Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `left_join` will choose all common variables:

```
left_join(df1,df2)
Joining by: c("ssuid", "epppnum")
         ssuid epppnum esex erace
1 916860000285     101    M     1
2 916860000285     102    F     1
3 916925451999     101    M     2
4 404454000285     101    M     1
5 404454000285     102    F     1
```

As you can see in the message above, to specify a combination, use `c` to combine them, ie `by = c("ssuid", "epppnum")`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data.table` without concatenating keys, the join will be done by mentionning keys with `setkey`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)
setkey(df1, ssuid, epppnum)[setDT(df2)]

#          ssuid epppnum esex erace
#1: 916860000285     101    M     1
#2: 916860000285     102    F     1
#3: 916925451999     101    M     2
#4: 404454000285     101    M     1
#5: 404454000285     102    F     1
```